# jQuery Air Passenger Seat Layout Example

Tags: jquery

I showed an extreme sample before 6 months. it is related to "Air routes". there is a plane map. you can select a seat.you are separated. Can you give me this link if you know where is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the jQuery that runs on the page when the DOM has loaded in [Corbin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960239/jquery-extreme-sample/960248#960248)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Disable various aspects of passenger details table
    $('#passenger_details input, #passenger_details select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // Add class="selected" to tab + tbody
    $('#tabs a:first, #passenger_details tbody:first').addClass('selected');

    // Get the value of the tab link, and display tbody
    $('#tabs a').click(function(){
        // Switch class="selected" for tabs
        $('#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        // Asign value of the link target
        var thisTarget = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show target tbody and hide others
        $('#passenger_details tbody').removeClass('selected');
        $(thisTarget).addClass('selected');
        this.blur();
        return false;
    });

    // Add click listener to seats
    $('#airplane a').click(function(){
        // Assign value of the link target
        var thisTarget = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show target tbody and hide others
        $('#passenger_details tbody').removeClass('selected');
        $(thisTarget).addClass('selected');

        // Swap out class="selected" for tab
        $('#tabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $('#tabs a[@href=' + thisTarget + ']').addClass('selected');

        // Assign the value of the parent <li class="*">
        var thisSeat = $(this).parent('li').attr('class');

        // Compare parent <li class="*"> against
        // <tr> in <table id="passenger_details">
        var thisRow = $('#passenger_details tr');
        for (var i = 0, j = thisRow.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (thisSeat == thisRow[i].className) {
                // Add class="selected" to row
                $(thisRow[i]).addClass('selected');

                // Enable inputs and selects so that they can be used
                $(thisRow[i]).children('td').children('input, select').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else 
                if (thisSeat + ' selected' == thisRow[i].className) {
                    // Remove class="selected" from row
                    $(thisRow[i]).removeClass('selected');

                    // Disable inputs and selects that aren't being used
                    $(thisRow[i]).children('td').children('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
                    $(thisRow[i]).children('td').children('select').each(function(){
                        this.disabled = true;
                        this.selectedIndex = 0;
                    });
                }
        }

        // Toggle selected class on/off
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        this.blur();
        return false;
    });

    // Assign function to master checkbox
    $('#check_all').click(function(){
        if (this.checked === true) {
            // Add class="selected" to seat
            $('#airplane a, #passenger_details tbody tr').addClass('selected');
            $('#passenger_details input, #passenger_details select').removeAttr('disabled');
            this.blur();
        }
        else {
            // Remove class="selected" from seat
            $('#airplane a, #passenger_details tbody tr').removeClass('selected');
            $('#passenger_details input').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
            $('#passenger_details select').each(function(){
                this.disabled = true;
                this.selectedIndex = 0;
            });
            this.blur();
        }
    });

    // Disable the form submission
    $('form').submit(function(){
        alert('This is only a test. Were it a real emergency, panic would ensue.');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This: http://www.digital-web.com/extras/jquery_crash_course/?

Comment: How can i change this? For example i need to change this like cinema saloon

Comment: I would ask a new question. This is a bit out-of-scope from what you originally asked (and probably out-of-scope for stackoverflow).

Comment: Sorry; i need modify this. i don't understand with you.

Comment: Open Firebug, look at how the page has been created, look at how the jQuery works, check out the CSS. Base your cinema saloon on what you see. And if you have any specific questions on the HTML, CSS or jQuery/JavaScript, post them on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can download the code/css/images from [here](http://ww.digital-web.com/articles/jquery_crash_course/).  The zip file is near the bottom of the page...about 4 paragraphs up where it says "download a zip of all the files used in this demo."